# Laravel 5.3 passport authentication: unable to compile view components with gulp

Tags: gulp, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I've been following the laravel's api token-based authentication using passport. I followed all the steps in [this](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13) screen cast by Taylor Otwell himself. To publish the passport Vue components, I ran the command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-components
```

and the components where rightly published in the `resources/assets/js/components` directory.
Next,I registered the some components in `resources/assets/js/app.js` file and here's the result:

```
require('./bootstrap');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

Vue.component(
    'passport-clients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-authorized-clients',
    require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-personal-access-tokens',
    require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

I ran the command `gulp` but gulp wasn't recognized so I installed with the following two commands:

```
npm install --global gulp-cli
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

Here is my `gulpfile.js` file by the way (at the root of my project):

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');
var gulp = require('gulp');


elixir(function(mix){
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js');
});
```

next a pasted the following components in the `home.blade.php` view file after logging in:

```
<passport-clients></passport-clients>
<passport-authorized-clients></passport-authorized-clients>
<passport-personal-access-tokens></passport-personal-access-tokens>
```

I now ran the command `gulp` in the root of my application and got the following error:

```
> Error: Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/awa/Desktop/laravel53/gulpfile.js:1:78)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I may be making some silly mistaker here but I just can't get my way out of it. I am new to Laravel. I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have Laravel Elixir installed. It is is not automatically installed with laravel, you need to run:

`npm install`

from the root of your project, which will download laravel elixir and all it's dependencies.